# Getting 'tuple' object is not callable in np.random.randn()

Tags: python, numpy, initialization, data-science, mlp

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randn(2, 4)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-6f0359bd85c3> in <module>()
  1 import numpy as np
----> 2 np.random.randn(2, 4)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Can't initialize mlp because of this, but don't understand why.

Comment: What's your numpy version?

Comment: `np.__version__ = '1.17.5'` and newer does not have this problem.